# Can I determine if a Grub menu.lst is valid on a virtual machine without rebooting?

Tags: grub, vps

There's a problem with Ubuntu running on my hosted VPS. All I have access to is a recovery console which allows me to mount the devices.

I've narrowed the problem down to a messed `menu.lst`. I have the kernel and initrd pointing to the correct images, but I have no idea what the drive identifiers are when the Virtual machine is started. Also, using the grub command line gives errors when attempting to access the drives.

I have no access to the VM when it is booting, so cannot see the actual error it reports or start the Grub console. There is nothing in the logs to suggest that the machine has got past Grub while booting.

Can anyone give me advice on what I can do to determine the drive identifiers, or anything else that might help?

Grub version is 0.97.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that the disk was named something unconventional (`vxda1`) after managing to somehow get into busybox. Once I knew this I was able to sort the problem easily by editing the `menu.lst`.

The problem was caused by `grub_update` which, when invoked, erased the contents of `menu.lst`. Reason unknown.